# libgdx Screen - How to set a new Screen by a String

Tags: java, string, class, libgdx, screen

I'm trying to set a new Screen by a String. I could use Class.forName(ScreenString) and that's cool, but it seems to have some problem with the function game.setScreen().

What I'm doing here is:

```
 Class<?> temp = null;
        if(something) try {
            temp = Class.forName("string1"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(something else) try {
            temp = Class.forName("string2"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        game.setScreen(new temp());
```

But I clearly have some syntax problem cause it tells me "temp" is not found.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is your goal? That looks pretty hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the fully qualified name for the `forName` method. You can't call `new temp()`. That syntax is saying you want an instance of the class `temp` which doesn't exist. `temp` is a variable. If your class has a no-argument constructor, you can instantiate it with:

```
Screen screen = temp.newInstance();
```

If you need to pass some parameters in, create a super class that all your levels extend:

```
public class MyScreen extends Screen {

    Game game;

    public void init (Game game){
        this.game = game;
    }
}
```

Now to load a level by name. Note that `forName` requires a *fully qualified* name so you have to tack on the package name.

```
public void loadLevelScreen (String name) {
    String packageName = getPackage().getName();
    Class<? extends MyScreen> screenClass = null;
    try {
        screenClass = Class.forName(packageName + "." + name).asSubclass(MyScreen.class);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        MyScreen screen = screenClass.newInstance();
        screen.init(this.game);
        setScreen(screen);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if it has only constructors with arguments?

Comment: I'm trying with game.setScreen((Screen) temp.getClass().getDeclaredConstructors(Game.class).newInstance(this.game));

but it doesn't take Game.class like a correct argument

Comment: The easy solution is to move the code from the constructor to a method and call that method right after instantiating the class.

Comment: If you want to do it your way, use `getDeclaredConstructor` not `getDeclaredConstructors`. The latter takes no arguments and returns an array of them.

Comment: Moreover it seems I can't cast a Class object to Screen. I think this is quite strange, and it's the last issue to face with in order to make it work

Comment: This doesn't work? `Screen screen = (Screen)(temp.newInstance());`

Comment: The instruction itself works but then when I pass screen into game.setScreen I have an "cannot risolve symbol" error on it

Comment: And even if I make a constructor without arguments and an "initialize" method to pass my parameters, how can I call this .initialize method on my temp object then? Since this wpuld be a method of the specific subclass found by "forName"

Comment: Instruction didn't work because your `temp` is a `Class<?>` rather than a `Class<? extends Screen>`. Create a superclass for them so they can all specify the same constructor or init method. See edit to answer above.

Answer (score 0):

What happened to:

```
if (something)
{
  game.setScreen(somethingScreen);
}
else if (somethingElse)
{
  game.setScreen(somethingElseScreen);
}
```

Cannot think of a way *why* to do it your way. If you have a string like "mainScreen" and "optionsScreen" just compare those in the statements.

If you somehow do want it your way you could try a `HashMap<String, Screen>`.

```
HashMap<String, Screen> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put("string1", new MainScreen);
map.put("String2", new OptionScreen);

if (something)
{
  game.setScreen(map.get("string1"));
}
else if (somethingElse)
{
  game.setScreen(map.get("string2"));
}
```

Feels a bit more natural to me.

As far as I know if you have `"lvl06"` you need to load level "06" and not "16" or "01". So you know before runtime what string maps to which level. So a simple statement is sufficient to link your `LevelScreens` to `Strings`.

Comment: I have many classes called "lv01" "lv02" ... "lv10" "lv11" and so on. I get the class name by an index which is checked runtime and the if statement is there because I could have "lv0" + index or "lv" + index depending of the variable, it could be more or less than 9.

Comment: Why would you have a class for each level? Do you mean objects derived from the same class? Anyway, you already know what Screen should be displayed when the string is `"lvl04"` right? Then both of my examples are sufficient and reflection is not needed.

Comment: Because each level is different from another. I can't understand your first example since setScreen need a Screen object and not a String

Comment: You mean each level is completely different? Like first level might be a FPS, the next level might be a RTS? I would normally have a single class (blueprint) to create levels and have many objects of that class to represent multiple levels. And yes, the quotes on the strings shouldn't be there, edited.

Comment: I mean that something is always the same and something else change, so I have my Level class and many classes which extend that

Comment: I do not know the goal your after but I'm not sure that is the right approach. When You have many classes with slight differences then you probably have a design issue. You should probably have many objects of a single class with slightly different fields. For example if I have a cars with 3 wheels and one 4 wheels I would create a single class and set different properties for those wheels when I create objects for these cars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an instance of your ScreenClass you have to call newInstance() on the Class Object like this:

```
game.setScreen((Screen) temp.newInstance());
```